# How to ping automatically to pingomatic in PHP?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I want to ping automatically to [pingomatic](http://pingomatic.com/), when ever i update my blog, as it is done by the wordpress. Pingomatic uses the XMLRPC, but I don't know how it works. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems quite easy at first sight. The form there is a plain HTML form with method=get and I don't see any XMLRPC code around. I'd say you just fill in the form once, click to submit and then copy the resulting URL from the address bar into a PHP `http_get()` or `fopen()`. The result page says *"Bookmark this page and come back to it later to automatically re-ping"*, so I'm pretty sure a plain GET request is enough and there is no other magic involved.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. The form over there uses the get method. But will it be the right way to ping it in such manner. I have studied about some of the XMLRPC protocol, which uses POST to ping the rpc servers. For pingomatic that is http://rpc.pingomatic.com/ . Do you have any idea how to work with this, and what is the format it accepts ?

Comment: I never really cared about XMLRPC, but I googled around and ended up looking at the source of Weblog_Pinger (http://workbench.cadenhead.org/weblog-pinger/). I still don't see any practical advantage in using such a roundabout way to just the same effect - it sure seems harder to debug to me.
As for the format, take a peek at http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=141370 or http://www.bpsdesigns.co.uk/blog/tutorials/how-to-send-xmlrpc-pings-from-classic-asp/ , still unconvincing but at least written in plaintext.