# PHP function to connect to pingomatic using cURL

Tags: php, proxy, curl

I'm creating a PHP function to connect to pingomatic using CURL but the response is always.

```
Array ( [EXE] => XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only. )
```

here is my sample code...

```
function curl_getpage2($url,$data, $referer = null, $agent = null, $header = null, $timeout = 20, $proxy = null, $proxy_username = null, $proxy_password = null) {
 //getProxy();
 if ($agent == null) {
     $agent = getAgent();
 }

 if ($referer == null) {
     $referer = getHost($url);
 }
 if (!is_array($header)) { 
  $header = array("Content-Type:text/xml","Host:".getHost($url),"User-Agent:$agent",
   "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
   "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5",
   "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate",
   "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
   "Keep-Alive:300",
   "Connection:keep-alive",
   "Cache-Control:max-age=0",
   "Content-length: ".strlen($XML));
 }

 if($proxy == null){
     $proxy = "208.100.27.155:60099";
 }

 if($proxy_username == null && $proxy_password == null){
     $proxyUnPW = "unproxy:pwproxy";
 }else{
     $proxyUnPW = $proxy_username.":".$proxy_password;
 }

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,$proxyUnPW);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,TRUE);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);       
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

        $result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
        //$result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
        //$result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
}
```

I need some help here. I'm just somewhat new to PHP.

Comment: What is your question? What about your sample code doesn't work as you want?

Comment: Can you also show the code which CALLS this function with the contents of `$data` and other variables.

Comment: What it's in `$XML` meybe insted of `strlen($XML))` put `strlen($data))`. Meybe you should remove `Content-length` from a header.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your site once via the web form and then call a GET request for that url (see 
question [How to ping automatically to pingomatic in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209463/how-to-ping-automatically-to-pingomatic-in-php/2219094#2219094)).

So your URL would be something like the following if you want to ping all services (title and url encoded with `urlencode()`):

```
$url = 'http://pingomatic.com/ping/?title='.$title.'&blogurl='.$url.'&rssurl=&chk_weblogscom=on&chk_blogs=on&chk_feedburner=on&chk_newsgator=on&chk_myyahoo=on&chk_pubsubcom=on&chk_blogdigger=on&chk_weblogalot=on&chk_newsisfree=on&chk_topicexchange=on&chk_google=on&chk_tailrank=on&chk_skygrid=on&chk_collecta=on&chk_superfeedr=on');
```

eg:

> http://pingomatic.com/ping/?title=Example%20Title&blogurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&rssurl=&chk_weblogscom=on&chk_blogs=on&chk_feedburner=on&chk_newsgator=on&chk_myyahoo=on&chk_pubsubcom=on&chk_blogdigger=on&chk_weblogalot=on&chk_newsisfree=on&chk_topicexchange=on&chk_google=on&chk_tailrank=on&chk_skygrid=on&chk_collecta=on&chk_superfeedr=on